# How to make WCF RESTful service work async?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm building WCF rest service and it's client. I plan, that client does not know much about the service, just right URL's to call methods and expected results.

My service contract is:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="/tasks")]
[OperationContract]
void SubmitTask(Transaction task);

[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/tasks/{taskId}")]
[OperationContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
Transaction GetTask(string taskId);
```

SubmitTask is realized like:

```
SubmitTask(Transaction task)
{
   DoSomethingWithTask(task);
   task.Status = "SomeStatus";
   DoSomethingElseWithTaks(task);
   task.Status = "SomeOtherStatus";
}
```

What I expect on client:

```
ButtonClick()
{
   SubmitTask(task);
   while(true)
   {
      string status = Transaction GetTask(task.taskId).Status;
      Textbox.Text+= status;
      if(status==ok)
         break;
      Thread.Sleep(1000); 
   }
}
```

The problem is - GetTask is not performed on service side, while all SubmitTask operations are completed, so I get only last task status on client side. How to realize asynchronos operation performing in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are you using async ?

Comment: What do you mean where? I make a method call, and I want it to perform on service before main method processing ends. Doesn't it means asynchronous work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this interesting little article? [Tweaking WCF to build highly scalable async REST API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234131/Tweaking-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-A) and the following article that is very good and which will hopefully provide the answer you desire [Fixing WCF to build highly scalable async REST API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234085/Fixing-WCF-to-build-highly-scalable-async-REST-API)